# Сделать даты всех постов уникальными MySQL Wordpress

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

Добавлял через скрипт сразу много статей, у всех поставились одинаковые значения даты постинга (2019-11-28 12:00). Как сделать запрос, чтобы они хотя-бы на минуту отличались. Из-за этого, записи в категории выводятся рандомно, не привязаны к конкретным страницам.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пример можно?..

Comment: Проще и правильнее это делать плагинами https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/random+date/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Версия сервера не указана, а жаль... ну сотворите нечто типа

```
UPDATE table t, ( SELECT MIN(id) AS N
                  FROM table
                  WHERE datetime = '2019-11-28 12:00' ) x
SET t.datetime = t.datetime + INTERVAL (t.id - x.N) MINUTE
WHERE t.datetime = '2019-11-28 12:00'
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=8c8283864c1b3f4cb7dc05b1bb52ff01)

Если "сразу много статей" - это реально много, то добавляемый интервал можно и "поджать". Скажем, до `t.datetime + INTERVAL 2 * (t.id - x.N) SECOND` - различаться будут, но дата не уползёт на следующий день.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, пока не получается сделать его валидным. Версия: 5.6.42-84.2

Comment: @WebFR *пока не получается сделать его валидным* Добавил fiddle - запрос валиден. Смотрите, в чём косячите...

Comment: Вижу что всё хорошо, но у меня ругается на эту конструкцию (прикрепил картинку к ответу). Я уже заменял таблицы и столбцы на свои, но ошибка не там выскакивает.

Comment: @WebFR Адресуйте претензии используемому клиенту, который неспособен переварить валидный запрос. Походу он просто не подозревает о существовании подзапросов.

Comment: Похоже, что так. Спасибо.

Comment: @WebFR В конце концов операция разовая - так что можете просто посмотреть, чему равно `MIN(id) AS N`, и подставить в UPDATE значением. `UPDATE table t SET t.datetime = t.datetime + INTERVAL (t.id - 123456) MINUTE WHERE t.datetime = '2019-11-28 12:00'`. Но уж если клиент и это не прожуёт...